# express.js response value as destruct

Tags: javascript, express, destructuring

I think this is kind of destructuring problems..

My node.js server have to return

```
{
    "result" : true,
    "values" : [{
            "request_id": <string>,
            "product_name": <string>,
            "ratio": <float>,
            "buyers": [


        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

but it returns

```
{"result":true,
"values":{"values":[{"results":[{"rank":1,"buyer_id":"Z0195841"},{"rank":2,"buyer_id":"Z0186008"},
```

I think this part is the problem.

```
 res.json({ "result" : true,
            "values" : values});
```

so I edit like this,

```
  res.json({ "result" : true,
               values});
```

it didn't works. still return

```
{"result":true,
"values":{"values":[{
```

How can I solve this??? please help.

Comment: Can you share more code? Where do you set "values"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a "value" inside other "value" key, try destructuring it, this way:

```
const { value } = value;

res.json({ 
    "result" : true,
    values
});
```

Comment: I don't have any `value` key

Comment: there is a `values` array has to be returned.

Comment: so, from where you get "values" to write in the response?... can you write more of your code?